# Create a mybatis dao template to execute dynamically any query

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have severals queries stored in database, and my goal is to create a mybatis dao that execute a selected query from my list.

Does anyone have idea on how to do this ? (Just one dao able to execute a passed query as parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by injecting variable verbatim using [string substitution](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#String_Substitution):

Mapper interface

```
List<Map<String, Object>> get(@Param("query") String query);
```

And xml mapping file:

```
<select id="get" resultType="hashmap" statementType="STATEMENT">
   ${query}
</select>
```